# Dynamic x-tick labels visualisation with Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have the following code:

```
library(plotly)
A <- matrix(seq(1, 365), nrow = 73, ncol = 5)
xaxis_names <- seq(from = as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2001-12-31"), by = 1)
p <- plot_ly(z = t(A), type = "heatmap", colorscale = "Greys") %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(dtick = 1,
                      ticktext = xaxis_names,
                      tickvals = 0:length(xaxis_names)))

p
```

The x-ticks labels are not been displayed in a suitable way. There go out of the plot window and there are too many. Hopefully, I would like them to appear dynamically depending on how much I zoom and see maybe 5 or 10 labels at once.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help? You can try specifying it as one of the axes, so that `plotly` can automatically figure out the best tick spacing.

```
library(plotly)
A <- matrix(seq(1, 365), nrow = 73, ncol = 5)
xaxis_names <- seq(from = as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2001-12-31"), by = 1)
p <- plot_ly(z = t(A), x = xaxis_names, type = "heatmap", colorscale = "Greys")
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the solution given by @Ameya, one can specify the maximum number of ticks for the xaxis using `nticks` with `type="auto"`:

```
library(plotly)
A <- matrix(seq(1, 365*5), nrow = 365, ncol = 5)
xaxis_names <- seq(from = as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2001-12-31"), by = 1)
p <- plot_ly(x=xaxis_names, z = t(A), type = "heatmap", colorscale = "Greys") %>%
     layout(margin = list(b=100),
            xaxis = list(type="auto", nticks=24,  tickformat="%x", tickangle=-90))
p
```

[image]